# check if a user is verified in twitter by twitter api

Tags: twitter

I am doing a project to identify if a user is a celebrity in Twitter. Are there any ways to check if a user in Twitter is verified as celebrity? I know a celebrity would identified with a blue badge in the twitter profile. But how could I retrieve the information through Twitter API and see if there is a blue badge?

Comment: https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-check-whether-the-user-has-been-verified/17630

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials (verified near the end)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Each Twitter user object](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) from `/users/show` comes with a `verified` boolean field. If the user is verified, it will be `true`; otherwise it will be `false`.

For example, a typical response from [my Twitter profile](http://twitter.com/jxxf) might look like:

```
{
  "name": "John Feminella",
  "screen_name": "jxxf",
  # ...
  "verified": true,          # True if the user is verified, false otherwise.
  # ...
}
```

Comment: that doesn't include twitter blue subscriptions...