# How to tell a user is verified using Tweepy, Python

Tags: python, tweepy

Given a user ID, I'd like to know whether they're a verified (blue check) Twitter user. I don't see anything in the documentation.. Is there any strategy I can use? For example:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = '...'
consumer_secret = '...'
access_token = '...'
access_token_secret = '...'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

ezra = api.get_user('ezraklein')
ezra.is_verified() ???
```

With the method returning `True`, as 'ezraklein' is a verified user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tweepy documentation is a bit lacking, but, [inspecting the source](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/aa3658e/tweepy/user.py#L105), you can clearly see that this property is parsed from the [API JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26790753/11647025).

Watch out, this is an attribute, not a method, so you have to check without parenthesis.

```py
>>> user = api.get_user("BarackObama")
>>> user.verified
True
```

EDIT: Updated the source link, fixing latest commit - `aa3658e` at time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping to help other people with this, but it's a simple `ezra.verified()` or `ezra.verified`. I don't know what python version you're using.

You may have to use a `str(...)` because it's a bool.

the output for a verified user will be True

the output for a nonverified user will be False